# Netbook with Android 4.1 freezes on load screen

Tags: boot, system-freeze, safe-mode

I'm using a brand new Craig 10-inch netbook. It came with Android 4.1 jelly bean by default. I've made no changes at all but on boot, the initial splash screen appears, the jelly beans seem to appear inside of the Andrew character, but then it just freezes. No mouse icon, no menus, nothing.

I've tried:

1. long-press of the power button (both on to off and off to on).
2. Holding F2 and/or F8 during power on or power off or just the load phase.
3. Pushing the factory reset button on the bottom of the device.

None of these have any effect, unfortunately.

I've also noticed some posts saying to hold the volume buttons during boot to get safe mode. This seems only for phones as this netbook has no volume buttons at all.

Are there any known remedies for this load screen freezing? I cannot access any menus or options that require the computer to actually be booted. How can I access safe mode or some other boot mode to try to restore?

Comment: Did it ever work?  If not, then it probably faulty. Best to return it.

Comment: It did work without a problem for the first five or so days (maybe 10 on/off power cycles before the problem started).

Comment: Can you remove the battery? It could be like my original (rev 1) Nexus 7, where the device flips out if it ever goes to 0% battery. The fix is to do a special key sequence to do a reset (not factory reset, though). Android doesn't have a safe mode.

Comment: In fact, the battery cannot be removed and the instruction manual says it is not user-replaceable. It was working fine for several uses in a row. There are many posts about booting into Android safe-mode (for example, [this link](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/how-to-boot-your-android-phone-or-tablet-into-safe-mode-for-troubleshooting).

Comment: Also, the battery had never gone close to 0% when this started. Since that, I've tried draining and recharging the battery, which seems to go fine, but the same frozen loading screen persists on startup.

Answer (score -1):

press "Fn" button and "F2" and "home"

Comment: Some explanation on what this will do would be appreciated.