# Repair generic android netbook

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I just dug out my old android noname netbook (Meteorit NB-10.HD) and i can't really find any information on the internet about it. When i start it, it shows the initial boot screen and then gets stuck on `A N D R O I D _`. Are there any generic key combinations that i can try to get in some kind of recovery menu or can i somehow plug it into the pc to flash TWRP/CWM onto it? Apperantly it uses Android 2.2

Comment: It's severely outdated so it would be hard to find a firmware to flash it via PC

Comment: If it was easy to find i'd ask google not stackexchange :)

Comment: These "generic" no name tablets are generally designed to be disposable... There is almost no chance of finding the stock image, TWRP/CWM, or a custom ROM. Honestly, the garbage or recycle bin is the best place for it. Plus the age, if it has Android 2.2 (Froyo), then if (and that's a big IF) you could find a ROM image the best it could likely be in Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) which is essentially unusable today.

Answer (score 0):

You could try flashing Android x86 project on it by putting it on an SD card:

1. Format the SD card (WARNING: THIS WILL ERASE ALL DATA ON IT).
2. Download `android-x86-2.2-generic.iso` from http://www.android-x86.org/download.
3. Download http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ and use it to install the image on the SD card (Note: This does NOT mean copy and pasting the `.iso` file).
4. Insert SD card into netbook.
5. Start recovery mode by pressing as soon as the netbook is switched on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75153/77275.
6. Choose option to install from SD card.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138170/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-kist-repair-generic-android-netbook).